# Запуск приложения написанного в visual studio в ios

Tags: ios, visual-studio

Можно ли программируя в среде visual studio 2019 приложение под ios тестировать и установить сразу на телефон, не имея maсбука?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Без наличия устройства, работающего на `macOS` и программы `xCode` нельзя. Можно запускать из-под `Windows` через `Visual Studio` если подключить mac-устройство по сети.